# Error while importing from github in android studio 2.3.3

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I listed the person's name in recycler view from the data I got from Firebase real-time database.

How can I show the details of the person when the user clicks the name of each person?

The description of each person stored in given image format:

[image]

Comment: what kind of error??

Answer (score 0):

Since there can be many user with the same name, I suggest you to fetch the details of your user by id. May be you can store your user Id in some view that is hidden.

You can follow below steps to fetch the detail your user by Id.

1. Make a class corresponding to your user fields in the Firebase database.

   ```
   public class UserDetail {
       private String uId;
       private String name;
       private String phoneNo;
       private String address;
       private String product;
       private String spinner;
       private String quantity;

       // Empty constructor
       // Getters and setters
   }
   ```
2. Make a DAO class corresponding to above class to fetch records from your database.

   ```
   public class UserDetailDao {

       private final FirebaseDatabase mDatabase;

       public UserDetailDao() {
           mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
       }
       public void getUserById(String id, OnResultFetched onResultFetched) {
           final UserDetail userDetail = null;

           mDatabase.getReference()
                   .child("users")
                   .child(id)
                   .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                           userDetail = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserDetail.class);
                           onResultFetched.onResult(userDetail);
                       }

                       @Override
                       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                           onResultFetched.onResult(null);
                       }
                   });
       } 

       // Callback interface 
        public interface OnResultFetched {
            public void onResult(UserDetail userDetail);
        }
   }
   ```
3. Now from any activity, you can get list of all users by:

   ```
    new UserDetailDao().getUserById(id_of_your_user, new UserDetailDao.OnResultFetched() {
               @Override
               public void onResult(UserDetail userDetail) {

                   // **** HERE IS YOUR USER ****

               }
           });
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot it really helps me a lot

Comment: If this solved your issue, could you please accept and upvote this answer. Thanks in advance :)